# QtWebEngine::initialize() with PyQT

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qml

I have code bellow:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
engine.load('main.qml')

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

and qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtWebEngine 1.2

Window {
    visible: true
    title: "HelloApp"

    WebEngineView{
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "http://google.com"
    }

}
```

When I am trying to run the app I see an error:
`WebEngineContext used before QtWebEngine::initialize() or OpenGL context creation failed.`

Question: how can I call `QtWebEngine::initialize()` in PyQT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full error message gives you a hint about what you should do to solve it:

```
Qt WebEngine seems to be initialized from a plugin. Please set Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts using QCoreApplication::setAttribute and QSGRendererInterface::OpenGLRhi using QQuickWindow::setGraphicsApi before constructing QGuiApplication.
WebEngineContext is used before QtWebEngineQuick::initialize() or OpenGL context creation failed.
```

You need to add `QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_ShareOpenGLContexts, True)` before initializing the `QGuiApplication` and don't forget the `QtCore` import. Qt 5 or 6 shouldn't matter in this case.

```
import sys

from PySide6 import QtCore
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_ShareOpenGLContexts, True)

app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
engine.load('main.qml')

sys.exit(app.exec())
```